# How to skip some column header text of DataTable and select the rest in datatable C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable like this:

[image]

As you can see, I have a monthly report that shows Presence and Absence of a student.

Well, now I want to skip First 4 columns i.e. Id,Name,Gender, Division and take the month dates in a variable.

I tried to store the Header Text in a variable **obj** like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<=dt.Rows.Count-1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 4; j <= dt.Columns.Count-1; j++)
    {
        string[] obj = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString().Split(',');
    }
}
```

But **obj** gives me value of the cell i.e. when it reaches the col 01-01-2020 it gives me A, but I want the header text (i.e. 01-01-2020).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want column names

```
var headers = LeaveReportDt.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Skip(4) 
    .Select(c => c.ColumnName)
    .ToArray();
```